# How to get a stable absolute path to paperclip attachment with ActiveMailer and capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, capistrano

This is probably more my issue than an issue with paperclip. However, I'm having trouble understanding the best way to reliably get the path to the file.

In development I can just call `@model.attachment.path` and get an absolute path. In production that returns something like:

`/home/deploy/apps/appname/releases/20160708230518/public/system/... etc`

Five or so revisions later that path no longer exists because Capistrano has kindly cleaned it up.

I could do something like

```
File.read("#{Rails.root}/public#{@model.attachment.path.split('public')[1]}"
```

but this feels a bit clunky.

I could specify `:path` on my `has_attached_file` in the model but the path wouldn't be the same in each environment the app needs to run.

I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  maybe there is a different way to solve the problem... You could get the path by just regex replacing `releases/20160708230518/` with `current` for all image paths.  But if I knew what you were trying to do, maybe we could come up with a better solution.

Comment: I'm hoping to embed an image uploaded by the user into an email. something like: `attachments.inline['logo.jpg'] = File.read(@paperclip_attachment)`

Comment: Ah - i see.  So if the mail is sent and you redeploy, now the link to the image is no longer valid, right?  What about sending a url instead of a file path? like `@model.attachment.url`

Comment: Good thinking... I don't know why I didn't try that. I could just specify the `image_tag domainname+@model.attachment.url` in the view. But the challenge still stands with other attachments that aren't images.

Comment: attachments that aren't images will still be downloadable via that url from paperclip.  you just can't as easily embed them in html email.  glad that helped.

Comment: ^^I meant actual email attachments, rather than attachments to a rails model. But thanks for your help to get past this silly mental block and the suggestions about regex if I ever run into another variant of this problem.